# More than one window being opened when filling a Webform

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

I have the following code to fill webform in an already opened Internet Explorer.

```
Sub L()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim SWs As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim PageTitle As String
On Error Resume Next
    u = 1
    'Looks at all windows in Windows
    For Each IE In SWs

        If (LCase(IE.FullName) Like "*iexplore*") = True Then
            If u <> 1 Then
                u = u + 1
            End If
 End If
 PageTitle = IE.Document.Title
        If InStr(PageTitle, "Home") Then

IE.Navigate "http://intranet.com/Webforms/TaskCreation.aspx"
Do 'Wait till the edit page is loaded.
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy

IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN1").Value = "A"
IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN2").Value = "B"
IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN14").Value = "C"

IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlRegion").Value = "28"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlSubRegion").Value = "33"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlPriority").Value = "23"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlClientCode").Value = "37"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlCompanyCode").Value = "62"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_DDL_COLUMN1").Value = "5978"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_DDL_COLUMN2").Value = "5966"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").Focus
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").Value = "13720"
IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").FireEvent ("onchange")

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")


IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlSubActivity").Value = "13735"

IE.Document.getElementById("Content_imgRequestRcvdDate").Click

IE.Visible = True

 End If

    Next IE

End Sub
```

This code was working fine yesterday. It finds the IE with pagetitle = Home and fill the form.

Although I did not change absolutely anything, today I have been getting this error: when the macro finishes executing, it opens new Internet Explorer windows.
Sometimes it opens one, even 4 windows.

Is this something wrong with the code?

Do you think I should remove the On error resume next ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: "Do you think I should remove the On error resume next ?" Well, let's see. What happens when you try doing just that? Does it fix or change the problem?

Comment: I get an error. Run time error: Automation error, unspecified error.

Comment: Ken, what I understood by debugging each line is: even after the Macro finds the Windows right by the Title and execute the action, it still keeps going on and on, looking for more windows with the same title. 
It has to be a way to stop after it finds the first one. I am not sure if I made myself clear enough..

Comment: That wasn't clear at all from your question. :-) Add an `Exit For` once you've run the `IE.Visible = True` line (before the `End If` that follows it), as that means you've found (and processed) the browser instance you're trying to update. (You should also learn to properly indent your code; it makes it much easier to match loops and conditionals.)

Answer (score 0):

The line `For Each IE in SWs` appears to create 3 instances of internet explorer, I have modified the code for `ShellWindows` instead of `SHDocVW.ShellWindows` and use the 'SW.Count' to set the number of windows to check. I've also removed the `on errors resume next` line as it made debugging easier, you may want to put it back in if it was there for a good reason.

```
Sub L()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim SWs As ShellWindows
Dim PageTitle As String
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim u As Integer

    Set SWs = New ShellWindows
    If SWs.Count > 0 Then
        For iCounter = 1 To SWs.Count
            Set IE = SWs.Item(iCounter - 1)

            If (LCase(IE.FullName) Like "*iexplore*") = True Then
                    If u <> 1 Then
                        u = u + 1
                    End If


                PageTitle = IE.Document.Title
                    If InStr(PageTitle, "Home") Then

                    IE.Navigate "http://intranet.com/Webforms/TaskCreation.aspx"
                    Do 'Wait till the edit page is loaded.
                    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy

                    IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN1").Value = "A"
                    IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN2").Value = "B"
                    IE.Document.getElementById("Content_TEXT_ALPHA_COLUMN14").Value = "C"

                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlRegion").Value = "28"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlSubRegion").Value = "33"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlPriority").Value = "23"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlClientCode").Value = "37"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlCompanyCode").Value = "62"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_DDL_COLUMN1").Value = "5978"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_DDL_COLUMN2").Value = "5966"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").Focus
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").Value = "13720"
                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlActivity").FireEvent ("onchange")

                    While IE.Busy
                        DoEvents
                    Wend
                    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")


                    IE.Document.Forms(0).Item("Content_ddlSubActivity").Value = "13735"

                    IE.Document.getElementById("Content_imgRequestRcvdDate").Click

                    IE.Visible = True

                End If 'If InStr(PageTitle, "Home")
            End If 'If (LCase(IE.FullName) Like "*iexplore*") = True
        Next iCounter


    End If 'If SWs.Count > 0 Then

Set IE = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```